# Error Rendering View

Tags: mvc, training-certification

I am trying to preview a page from Sitecore Rock, from VS but I get this error. I have a Layouts, and I have putted that layouts in _Standard Values of that page. I don't know where is the problem now with this error.

Error Rendering View: /Views/TAC/Events/Layouts/Events.cshtml: Error while rendering view: '/Views/TAC/Events/Layouts/Events.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

[image]

Comment: You have a reference to `sitecoredemo` namespace in your view. And compiler cannot find it. What is your view code? Where that namespace comes from? Is it referenced from the web project?

Comment: The connection between the projects is throw Sitecore>Project Properties>Sitecore Explorer Connection. In the view I have the reference of Sitecore.Mvc. I have created even a Quick Publish between the two projects.

Comment: what is full namespace of sitecoredemo?

Comment: sitecoredemo.dev.local

Comment: Put content of your  /Views/TAC/Events/Layouts/Events.cshtml view into your question also content of Web.config file that sits in your Views folder

Answer (score 6):

The issue happens because you've added the namespace of your project in the `Views/web.config` file while you haven't created any class yet.

> Sitecore Labs Guide, Page 50

[image: Sitecore Labs Guide]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the link field. For suppose if I add the wrong value in type(internal link) with the value of the url as (http://www.google.com). The link field is of type external link but not the internal in content.

Comment: Yeah, based on the data you have entered it will automatically updated the type of the Link, you can check the raw value of the particular field.